# How do I respond to the last MDI childform closing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mdi

My goal is to respond to the last child form of an mdi container closing(for example, close the parent itself or show something new). The problem I face is that the mdi container's MdiChildren collection still indicates that the container contains children.

The approach I have tried is

```cs
void childMdiForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MdiChildren.Any())
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

`MdiChildren.Count()` is still 1 after the last child form is closed.

I have the same results by trying to handle the `parentform.MdiChildActivate` event.

The `MdiChildren` collection appears to not be updated yet when the child form has closed. The same occurs when there are multiple children: it will still contain all the crildren, it appears to update the collection at a later moment.

Is this the right approach? If not, how can I get an accurate count of the number of mdi children after closing a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinForms can be a little quirky at times and this is one example of that. I am not entirely sure why closing the last MDI child does not make the `MdiChildren` property return an empty array immediately thereafter.

In most cases you're going to be keeping track of either the children forms or the data models yourself, so I would simply keep a local array for managing this:

```
    List<Form> childForms = new List<Form>();

    void AddChildWindow()
    {
        var window = new ChildForm();
        window.MdiParent = this;
        window.Tag = Guid.NewGuid();

        window.FormClosed += (sender, e) => { OnMdiChildClosed(sender as Form, e.CloseReason); };
        window.Shown += (sender, e) => { OnMdiChildShown(sender as Form); };

        window.Show();
    }

    void OnMdiChildShown(Form window)
    {
        childForms.Add(window);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Child form shown: {0}", window.Tag));
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of MDI children: {0}", childForms.Count));
    }

    void OnMdiChildClosed(Form window, CloseReason reason)
    {
        childForms.Remove(window);

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Child form closed: {0} (reason: {1})", window.Tag, reason));
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of MDI children: {0}", childForms.Count));

        if (childForms.Count == 0)
        {
             // Do your logic here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I consider this to be the better approach, as it requires no knowledge from the reader about the event order to understand the code. The problem of the mdichildren list not getting updated remains strange, though..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the MdiChildren property doesn't get updated until *after* the FormClosed event is delivered.  There's a universal solution for event order issues like this, you can elegantly get code to run after event handing is completed by using the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  This code solves your problem:

```
protected override void OnMdiChildActivate(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnMdiChildActivate(e);
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        if (this.MdiChildren.Length == 0) {
            // Do your stuff
            //...
            MessageBox.Show("None left");
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: While I do not doubt this works, it still seems somewhat like a hack. Which MDI child is being activated and why would activation take place after the final form is closed?

Again, I completely believe it works, just saying that it seems a bit counterintuitive and could be confusing to developers at first glance.

Comment: It is a very old trick used by Windows GUI programmers, PostMessage() is the underlying mechanism.  Nobody ever called it "hack", just another tool in the box.  It has *many* uses, solves this problem as well.

Comment: While you may refer to it as a trick, I would say it is a hack or workaround for an underlying implementation issue. The `Form` object has both a `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` event. It would only seem logical that the `MdiChildren` collection should contain the closed child form in `FormClosing` but not by the time `FormClosed` fires. The fact that the behavior is not this way is a bit confusing, hence this SO question. Your code snippet, while effective, is not obvious at first glance. If I saw this I would ask, "why are we overriding `MdiChildActivate` instead of `FormClosed` event?"

Comment: You'll have to get off my back about "hack", I used the word "elegant" quite intentionally.  Using the FormClosed event is not elegant, forget to subscribe one and it still doesn't work.  Not a problem with MdiChildActivate, it only has to be subscribed once.

Comment: I apologize if you took offense to my statement. I was not trying to call your code bad or hackish. Your implementation is good code, it is simple and centralized. I do like the benefit of a single overloaded method instead of event handlers for the exact reasons you mention. However, I feel that you are required to do this *because* of WinForms bad implementation. While it works great, it is still a workaround for the silly implementation of `MdiChildren` which Microsoft is at fault for, not you. My point is merely that your code would not be immediately obvious as to "why" it is necessary.

Comment: I assume this works because the anonymous method isn't called until after it falls out of the OnMdiChildActive() method? This is a really neat 'trick'. I can think of many instances where this could save a ton of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full test example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class mdiMainForm : Form
    {
        private List<Form> _children = new List<Form>();

        public mdiMainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mdiMainForm_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.MdiParent = this;
            f3.FormClosed += mdiChildClosed;
            _children.Add(f3);
            f3.Show();
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
            f4.MdiParent = this;
            f4.FormClosed += mdiChildClosed;
            _children.Add(f4);
            f4.Show();
            Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.MdiParent = this;
            f5.FormClosed += mdiChildClosed;
            _children.Add(f5);
            f5.Show();
        }

        private void mdiChildClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_children.Contains((Form)sender))
                _children.Remove((Form)sender);
            if (_children.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("all closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to imply you are checking the child Form's MdiChildren collection.  But perhaps I'm misreading your code.

Use the MDI Form's 'MdiChildActivate' event:

```
private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(this.MdiChildren.Length == 0) {
        // replace with your "Do Stuff" code
        MessageBox.Show("All Gone");
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed code to use an event rather then a timer.  Much better.

Comment: As said, when the `MdiChildActivate` event triggers the MdiChildren collection still has items in it

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is very late, but I have a much simpler solution to the problem than what has been provided so I'll share it here.

```
    private void ChildForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // If WinForms will not remove the child from the parent, we will
        ((Form)sender).MdiParent = null;
    }
```